# Problemas con create-react-app, mongodb y graphql. ¿como usar un solo puerto?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, mongodb, localhost, graphql

sé que sonará un poco raro pero es que soy nuevo en esto de react y el proyecto que estoy haciendo es el primera aplicación web. Lo quiero montar en un hosting y hacerlo publico para que se pueda usar. Les quiero resaltar que no dispongo de conexión a internet en mi casa porque es muy caro para mi. A veces voy a un cybert a descargar los modulos que necesito para trabajar y el internet así igual sigue siendo caro para mi. Pero de a poco  estoy aprendiento react y graphql

mis inquietudes son las siguientes:

1. cuando intento conectarme a una base de datos de mongoDB. Este me tira error como en esta imagen.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me dice que connect que es un método del modulo “mongoose” no es una función. La cosa es que yo intento hacer la conexión en la carpeta src de mi proyecto react creada con npx créate-react-app. Ósea no se puede hacer aquí en “/src”. Yo la intento hacer es cuando ejecuto el comando npm start. Vi en videos que la conexión si se puede hacer pero instalando todo lo necesario de react por separado. Y eso para mi es u poco tedioso. Lo otro sería levantar otro servidor que no este usando react de créate-react-app como por ejemplo “localhost:4000”, ósea no se puede usar la conexión de react que es localhost:3000?. Es decir obtener de alguna manera la conexión que usar react para conectarme a mongodb. Lo que me lleva a mi otra inquietud con graphql…

2. para usar graphql he visto en videos que los youtubers montan otro servidor aparte de react y de ahí se hacen “Consultas” y “Mutaciones” con mongoDB o MySQL lo cual me confundió porque pensé que tendría que contratar como tres servidores-hostings; uno para react, otro para el servidor graphql y otro más para mongoDB atlas jajaja XD. Pero vi un ejemplo en un video en el cual se levanta el servidor manualmente, se instala todo lo necesario para usar React manualmente también sin necesidad de ejecutar npx creat-react-app, pero se usa una REST API en este proyecto de ejemplo. Al momento de que react use la REST API , react usa el mismo puerto “localhost:3000” levantado manualmente y así la aplicación consume los datos de mongoDB usando rutas de “express”. Me imagino que con graphql se puede hacer lo mismo. Lo cual me lleva a otra pregunta mas.
3. Al momento de traducir el código de react con npm build de create-react-app y trabajar con dos servidores-puertos ejemplo “react: localhost: 3000” y “servidor-graphql: localhost:4000”. Si quiero subir mi aplicación a un servidor-hosting, como se solucionaría este problema de los dos puertos, ósea como se le hace para que react (de créate-react-app) y el servidor graphql usen el mismo puerto cuando ya la aplicación este en producción. Alguien me da alguna explicación para este proceso por favor. Les recuerdo que es mi primera app web saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia. Además, haría falta ver el código de lo que tengas imolementado, para determinar dónde está el error. Por último, una aplicación web se compone (generalmente) de 2 partes: *backend* y *frontend*, siendo que estás creando una app con React (*frontend*) no veo dónde o en qué momento quieres hacer una conexión a MongoDB, ya que esa lógica la maneja el *backend* y no el *frontend*. Saludos

Comment: En cuanto a tu duda con los puertos, cuando levantas tu aplicación ejecutando `npm start`, lo haces usando un servidor (*webpack*) de desarrollo. El mismo transpila todo tu código en memoria y levanta un servidor web que escucha peticiones en el puerto configurado. Sin embargo, esto no es usado en producción. Para poner tu aplicación en producción, debes ejecutar `npm run build` que creará todos los archivos necesarios en una carpeta (usualmente `dist`) para que los subas a tu servidor de producción (*hosting*). Más info en la [documentación](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/).